# oci_bind_by_name() returns error

Tags: php, oracle

I'm using PHP to query oracle DB and everything works great unless i try to use oci_bind_by_name to replace a variable

```
$link = oci_connect("user","password","server/service");

$sql = "SELECT name FROM customers WHERE name LIKE '%:name%'";
$query= oci_parse($link, $sql);

$name = "Bruno";
oci_bind_by_name($query, ":name", $name);
$execute = oci_execute($query);
```

I also tried to escape the quotes like this, but it returns the same error, i assume it's a problem with the wildcards %

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM customers WHERE name LIKE \"%:name%\" ";
```

The error is not specific:

```
( ! ) Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): in D:\gdrive\www\sites\pulseiras\php\engine.php on line 30
```

I'd like to use bind by name to avoid sql injection, how can i make it work ?

Answer (score 1):

OCI is inserting the bound variable to your query and ending up with something like this:

```
SELECT name FROM customers WHERE name LIKE '%'Bruno'%'
```

Obviously a couple of unnecessary quotes have been added. This happens because a bound variable is treated as a single item.

You need to modify the variable before you bind, so:

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM customers WHERE name LIKE :name"; // chars removed.
$query= oci_parse($link, $sql);

$name = "%Bruno%"; // chars added.
oci_bind_by_name($query, ":name", $name);
```

As usual, the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php#refsect1-function.oci-bind-by-name-examples) has many useful examples.

Comment: this solution works as well :) i posted at the same time as you so i guess now there are two solutions for the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's amazing how the brain only seems to start working after posting the question on stackoverflow. It turns out the solution is to isolate the wildcards and concatenating with the variable:

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM customers WHERE name LIKE '%' || :name || '%' ";
$name = "Bruno";
oci_bind_by_name($query, ":name", $name);
$execute = oci_execute($query);
```